# How to calculate a count of users who did a thing X times during a rolling 7-day period in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate a count of unique users who have posted *5 or more* times over the course of a 7-day rolling period. How do I do this?

I know how to calculate a count of users who have posted *1 or more* times over the course of a 7-day rolling period. The query looks like this:

```
with PostsPerDay as (
  select cast(CreationDate as Date) [Day]
  , OwnerUserId [User]
  , count(*) Post
from Posts
where CreationDate > '2017-07-01'
group by 
  cast(CreationDate as Date)
  , OwnerUserId
)

select [Day], count(distinct [User]) DailyPosters, Rolling7DayCount
from PostsPerDay

outer apply (
  select count(distinct [User]) Rolling7DayCount
  from PostsPerDay ppd
  where ppd.[Day] >= dateadd(dd, -7, PostsPerDay.[Day])
  and ppd.[Day] < PostsPerDay.[Day]
  ) Rolling7DayCount

group by [Day], Rolling7DayCount
order by 1
```

[Here it is at the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/701531/rolling-7-day-count-of-posters#graph).

#### Desired Results

Ideally I'm looking for a four-column result: `Day`, `DailyPosters`, `Rolling7DayCount`, `Rolling7DayCount5xPosters`. (The sample query returns the first 3 columns.)

[image]

To be extra clear: I'm hoping to count users who have posted 5x over the course of any 7 day period ending on a specific date. So simply adding a `Having` to the CTE won't give me what I need.

Any performance tips would be appreciated, too!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added details on desired results. The sample data is from SEDE and I've [added the query there](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/701531/rolling-7-day-count-of-posters#graph). Hope that helps others help me.

Answer (score 1):

In your "PostsPerDay" CTE change it to this:

```
SELECT
     CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) [Day]
    ,OwnerUserId
    ,COUNT(*) Post
FROM
    Posts
WHERE
    CreationDate > '2017-07-01'
GROUP BY
     CAST(CreationDate AS DATE)
    ,OwnerUserId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

I only added the "HAVING" filter.

Comment: I think this isn't quite right as it will filter out all days for a user where fewer than 5 posts were made. In fact, I want to filter out users who haven't posted 5x over the course of any 7 day period ending on a specific date. Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I'll edit it for clarity.

Comment: Do you want the rolling period prior to your start date, or only on or after your start date of "2017-07-01" in your example?

Comment: it doesn't really matter. The result set has to start somewhere =) In this case, I limited the dataset to only July and after events due to perf concerns. If you [try it out in SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/701531/rolling-7-day-count-of-posters#graph) (without caching) you can see the query is not fast.

Answer (score 1):

After some troubleshooting and a bit of help from Stack Overflow developer [@BenjaminHodgson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson?tab=profile), I figured it out.

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1 = '20170601' -- start date
SET @Date2 = '20170726';-- end date

with Days as (
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
),
-- create calendar of days
cal as (
select *
from Days
),

data as (
select 
  cal.[Date]
  , x.OwnerUserId [User]
  , x.PostsLast7Days
from cal
cross apply (
  select
    OwnerUserId
    , count(*) PostsLast7days
  from Posts
  where CreationDate between dateadd(dd, -7, cal.[Date]) and cal.[Date]
  group by OwnerUserId
  ) x
)

select
  distinct Date,
  sum(case when PostsLast7days > 0 then 1 else 0 End) [Sent >= 1 Posts in Preceding 7 Days],
  sum(case when PostsLast7days >= 5 then 1 else 0 End) [Sent >= 5 Posts in Preceding 7 Days],
  sum(case when PostsLast7days >= 10 then 1 else 0 End) [Sent >= 10 Posts in Preceding 7 Days],
  sum(case when PostsLast7days >= 20 then 1 else 0 End) [Sent >= 20 Posts in Preceding 7 Days]

from data
group by Date

order by 1 asc
```

You can see the code in action at [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/701926/count-of-users-who-posted-1-5-10-or-20x-in-preceding-30-day-rolling-period#graph).